# Tool to run units tests automatically in the multiple environment

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, virtualization

I have set of Visual Studio solutions which have unit tests.

I want to run them in the multilple environments on the virtual machines. Basically I want to run ALL tests in the some set of snapshots of the VMs.

I can do it using VMWare or MS SCVMM environment and bat/bash/PowerShell files (Start VM > Run MS Unit utils > Collect and compress results and log files > Revert VM > Start new VM). This approach is very simple, but I want have more complex system.

Who knows, are there any tools (free or commercial) to run unit tests on the virtual machines, collect results and send them by e-mail?
It would be nice if this tools have remote interface (web or another) to run and configure tests.
Also it would be nice if this tool can be integrated with the MS SCVMM environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buildserver with running agents on each machine, rather simple to setup with [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue when I had start to use MS Team Server **2010**.

It has all functionality which I want.